# The import com.google.common.hash cannot be resolved

Tags: guava

Sorry for the Java newbie question folks.

I figure it is something I've missed (Muppet moment).

- I have the guava-gwt-11.0.1.jar in the project.
- I can get com.google.common.math to resolve.
- Gin and Guice resolve OK

so I think i have it in the libraries properly.

Am I missing an inherits or something?

Comment: Indeed, if you look at the content of the jar, no such package exists. That package doesn't even exists in the guava-gwt source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a look, none of the classes in that package are annotated with `@GwtCompatible`. I couldn't find any reason of this in the wiki, previous issues or the mailing list. So you probably should fill an issue requesting to have the classes in the package annotated with that annotation. It will be, if it makes sense, of course.